# There is a question related with trigonometry and geometry, and I cant't do it. Can you help me, please?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Let $λ$ be a positive real number. Consider a semicircle of center $O$ and diameter $AB$. Choose points $C$ and $D$ ($C$ is between $D$ and $B$) on the semicircle and let $∠ AOD=2α$ and $∠ BOC=2β$.

The point $X$ on the line $CD$ is such that $\dfrac{XD}{XC}=λ$. Prove that when $α$ and $β$ satisfy the relationship $\space\tan(α)=\tan(β)+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, the perpendiculars to all possible $CD$s at $X$ pass through a fixed point.

[image: ConcurrentPerpendiculars]

I found that $λ$ is 1. Due to the reason that OCD is an isosceles triangle, bisector, height, and median are the same. XD=XC. XD/XC=1

I need to find the answer because it is the topic I have chosen to work on during one summer school, and I am stuck. And I have to do it until tomorrow.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be true.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: FYI: My rough Geogebra sketch suggests that the result is true. (That is, for fixed $\lambda$ and varying $\beta$, the perpendicular at $X$ to line $CD$ appears to go through some fixed point.)

Comment: The goal isn't to "find" $\lambda$. Rather, as suggested in my previous comment, the goal is to show that, *for any given $\lambda$*, the perpendicular at $X$ goes through some fixed point as $\beta$ varies. Certainly, the case of $\lambda=1$ is trivial (the fixed point is the center of the circle). Proving the general case would seem to be trickier.

Comment: But how can I prove it?

Comment: @NurlanMammadli: *"But how can I prove it?"* I have no idea how *you* can prove it, since your question says nothing about the kinds of tools or techniques you know or are allowed/expected to use. (This is the "context" the community likes to see in questions. When you provide little more than a statement of the problem, we can't tell how best to assist you.) That said, I'm not sure how *I* can prove it, either. :) I'd probably start by picking two convenient cases, determining the pt where the perpendiculars from those cases meet, then (somehow) proving that the pt is independent of $\beta$.

Comment: @Blue Did you notice that the supposed intersection points of the triplets of perpendiculars lie on a straight line that passes through the center of the semicircle?

Comment: @YNK: I didn't play with things *too* much (I've been waiting/hoping for OP to show some effort), but the few cases I tried *did* seem to suggest a linear relation.